# R neuralNet: "non-conformable arguments"

Tags: r, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, survival-analysis

Argh! I keep getting the following error when attempting to `compute` with my neural network:

```
> net.compute <- compute(net, matrix.train2)
Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : non-conformable arguments
```

I can't figure out what the problem is. Below I'll provide you with an example data and formatting from my matrices and then I'll show you the code I'm attempting to run.

- `matrix.train1` is used for training the network

  ```
  > matrix.train1
      (Intercept) survived pclass sexmale    age sibsp parch     fare embarkedC embarkedQ embarkedS
  1             1        0      3       1  22.00     1     0   7.2500         0         0             1
  2             1        1      1       0  38.00     1     0  71.2833         1         0         0
  3             1        1      3       0  26.00     0     0   7.9250         0         0         1
  4             1        1      1       0  35.00     1     0  53.1000         0         0         1
  5             1        0      3       1  35.00     0     0   8.0500         0         0         1
  6             1        0      3       1 999.00     0     0   8.4583         0         1         0
  7             1        0      1       1  54.00     0     0  51.8625         0         0         1
  8             1        0      3       1   2.00     3     1  21.0750         0         0         1
  9             1        1      3       0  27.00     0     2  11.1333         0         0         1
  10            1        1      2       0  14.00     1     0  30.0708         1         0         0
  11            1        1      3       0   4.00     1     1  16.7000         0         0         1
  ```
- `matrix.train2` is a slice of the training data used for testing the model

  ```
  > matrix.train2
      (Intercept) pclass sexmale    age sibsp parch     fare embarkedC embarkedQ embarkedS
  1             1      1       1  49.00     1     1 110.8833         1         0         0
  2             1      3       1  42.00     0     0   7.6500         0         0         1
  3             1      1       0  18.00     1     0 227.5250         1         0         0
  4             1      1       1  35.00     0     0  26.2875         0         0         1
  5             1      3       0  18.00     0     1  14.4542         1         0         0
  6             1      3       1  25.00     0     0   7.7417         0         1         0
  7             1      3       1  26.00     1     0   7.8542         0         0         1
  8             1      2       1  39.00     0     0  26.0000         0         0         1
  9             1      2       0  45.00     0     0  13.5000         0         0         1
  10            1      1       1  42.00     0     0  26.2875         0         0         1
  11            1      1       0  22.00     0     0 151.5500         0         0         1
  ```

The only real difference between the two matrices is that `matrix.train2` doesn't contain the `survived` column.

Here's the R code I'm attempting to run:

```
#Build a matrix from training data 
matrix.train1 <- model.matrix(
  ~ survived + pclass + sex + age + sibsp + parch + fare + embarked, 
  data=train1
)

library(neuralnet)

#Train the neural net
net <- neuralnet(
  survived ~ pclass + sexmale + age + sibsp + parch + fare + embarkedC + 
  embarkedQ + embarkedS, data=matrix.train1, hidden=10, threshold=0.01
)

#Build a matrix from test data
matrix.train2 <- model.matrix(
  ~ pclass + sex + age + sibsp + parch + fare + embarked, 
  data=train2
)

#Apply neural net to test matrix 
net.results <- compute(
  net, matrix.train2
)

Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : non-conformable arguments
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

---

Updates based on comments so far:

1. Using the solution from "[*Predicting class for new data using neuralnet*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939591/predicting-class-for-new-data-using-neuralnet)" doesn't seem to work.

   ```
   > net.compute <- compute(net, matrix.train2[,1:10])
   Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : non-conformable arguments
   ```
2. I'm manually putting my `train1` and `train2` data frames into matrices via `model.matrix` because if I don't I get the following error:

   ```
   > Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : 
   requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
   ```

Note: see the following thread for more details on why I'm using `model.matrix`: "[*Working with neuralnet in R for the first time: get “requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments” but don't know how to correct*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457028/working-with-neuralnet-in-r-for-the-first-time-get-requires-numeric-complex-ma)".

Comment: What package are you using?

Comment: I'm using the `neuralnet` package. In case it matters, the IDE I'm using is RStudio.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you need to remove the predictor variable. Try this:

```
nn_pred<-compute(nn,test[,3:11])
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried this with the neuralnet package as well. I think if you instead of

```
net.results <- compute(
  net, matrix.train2
```

do

```
net.result <- compute(  
     net, matrix.train2[,c("pclass",   
     "sexmale", "age", "sibsp", "parch",   
     "fare","embarkedC","embarkedQ","embaredS")])
```

it should work. The names of the variables needs to be in the exact order of the `model.list$variables`, so you can also type

```
net.result <- compute(  
     net, matrix.train2[, net.result$model.list$variables])
```

I hope this helps. The reason is - I think - that neuralnet has a problem finding out which variables are in your net and which in the matrix... so you match them explicitly instead.

Comment: Thank you. Solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the neuralnet ackage, but unless it's doing something weird you shouldn't be calling `model.matrix` like that. `neuralnet` has a formula interface, so it will call `model.matrix` for you. You just have to give it the training data frame `train1`.

This also applies for predicting on test data. Don't create a model matrix; just pass it the data frame `train2`.

Comment: I wasn't calling `model.matrix` originally but when I passed in the data frame directly I got a `requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments` error. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457028/working-with-neuralnet-in-r-for-the-first-time-get-requires-numeric-complex-ma for more details regarding why I'm using model.matrix

Comment: Good lord, is that neuralnet code hideous. This doesn't answer your question, but maybe you should try using `nnet` in package `nnet` (part of the base R install). It only does single-hidden-layer MLPs and uses quasi-Newton rather than flavours of backprop, but at least it knows how to handle factors.

Comment: And by "handle factors" I mean everything that the standard `model.frame`/`model.matrix` approach gives you: ability to deal with missing values, subset your data, do predictions easily on new data (without having to worry about the ordering of columns), and so on.

Comment: Even though this didn't directly answer my question, it did turn me onto `nnet` which in turn got me to look at the `caret` package, which is awesome. I'd heard about `caret` before but hadn't yet looked into it. It looks awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the answer used for this questions,[predicting class for new data using neuralnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939591/predicting-class-for-new-data-using-neuralnet)

Comment: Still no luck. `> net.compute <- compute(net, matrix.train2[,1:10])
Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : non-conformable arguments`

Comment: when you use model matrix for train2: `matrix.train2 <- model.matrix(
  ~ pclass + sex + age + sibsp + parch + fare + embarked, 
  data=train2)` you dont specify embarkedC, embarkedQ, embarkedS. Maybe this is why you keep getting the error because the apparent different data it needs to compare. Why don't you try to run your actual code with `+embarkedC + embarkedQ + embarkedS` modification

Comment: I wish it were that simple! The "embarked" vector has three levels: C, Q, and S. When I run the model.matrix function, the function automatically slices each level into its own variable so that they follow the binary format. So instead of "embarked = C, Q, or S" we get embarkedC = 1/0, embarkedQ = 1/0, embarkedS = 1/0. This is an automatic part of the function so I don't need to specify it when running model.matrix, but when I use the matrix for training I have to account for the new variables.

Answer (score 0):

change the `neuralnet` train to this

```
t <- neuralnet(
survived ~ pclass + sexmale + age + sibsp + parch + fare + embarkedC + 
embarkedQ + embarkedS)
```

change the predictor variable to

```
NN_pred<-compute(t,test[,1:9])
```

it should have the same order of the data taken in a model